# Declaring "friend" functions fails under Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, friend-function

I am trying to declare a global function as a "friend" of a class:

```
namespace first
{
    namespace second
    {
        namespace first
        {
            class Second
            {
                template <typename T> friend T ::first::FirstMethod();
            };
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile this code under Visual C++ 2008 I get:

```
error C3254: 'first::second::first::Second' : class contains explicit override 'FirstMethod' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration
error C2838: 'FirstMethod' : illegal qualified name in member declaration
```

If I use `template <typename T> friend T first::FirstMethod();` instead I get:

```
error C2039: 'FirstMethod' : is not a member of 'first::second::first'
```

What is the appropriate way of declaring friend functions?

Comment: More generally, I think it's a very bad idea to nest identic identifiers (`first` and `first`) it really is likely to confuse not only the reader, but the compiler too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have hit [my quiz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358524/why-does-this-separate-definition-cause-an-error) by accident - the sequence `T ::first:: ...` is interpreted as a *single* name. You need to put some token in between the colons and `T`. Solution is presented in the linked question too.

Notice that in any case you first have to declare the function designated by a qualified name in its respective namespace, too.

---

*Edit:* There are different solutions for the syntax problem

```
 template <typename T> friend T (::first::FirstMethod)();
 template <typename T> T friend ::first::FirstMethod();
```

If you often need to refer to the outer namespace and have problems with this syntax, you can introduce a namespace alias

```
    namespace first
    {
        namespace outer_first = ::first;
        class Second
        {
            template <typename T> friend T outer_first::FirstMethod();
        };
    }
```

Comment: why is `T ::first::` interpreted as a single name ? if it were a single name there would need to be the `typename` prefix wouldnt it ?

Comment: @smerlin, it's a non-type name. That means that the declaration declares the name `T::first::FirstMethod`, and specifies no type for that name. Semantically that makes no sense, and makes VC++08 spit out confusing error messages. Clang's diagnostic is much better: "error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations". Of course you can prefix it by "typename", in which case it acts as a type-specifier and the member-name is missing. Clang then says "error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers"